# Convert python pickle from protocol 5 to protocol 4

Tags: python, pickle

Problem:

Under Python 3.8 MLflow logs Scikit-Learn models using pickle protocol 5. However, python 3.7 only supports pickle protocol 4, so the models cannot be loaded by scikit-learn.

I wonder, whether it's possible for a python 3.8 script to automatically convert pickle v5 data to pickle v4. Basically, I want to do `pickle.dump(picle.load(data), protocol=4)`. The problem with this is that this requires all the packages and modules used inside the pickled data to be installed. But maybe there is a way to do a lower-level to do transcoding without reconstructing all objects. Just converting the pickle data stream.

Is it possible to convert pickle v5 data to pickle v4 data stream without recontructing all pickled objects?

**Update 1**:

I've checked the pickle disassembly for mlflow autologging from python 3.7 and python 3.8:

In python 3.7:

```
#     0: \x80 PROTO      4
#     2: \x95 FRAME      65694
#    11: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'sklearn.ensemble._forest'
#    37: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 0)
#    38: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'RandomForestRegressor'
...
```

In python 3.8+:

```
#     0: \x80 PROTO      5
#     2: \x95 FRAME      70185
#    11: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'sklearn.ensemble._forest'
#    37: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 0)
#    38: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'RandomForestRegressor'
...
```

The python 3.8 pickle uses `BYTEARRAY8`.

// I wonder why does `BYTEARRAY8` need to exist when there is already `BINBYTES8`. Is it just to save time and memory converting from `bytes` to `bytearray`?

Maybe it's possible to convert the `BYTEARRAY8` opcode to `BINBYTES8` plus call to the `bytearray` constructor.

**Update 2**:

It looks like NumPy arrays are pickled/unpickled differently:

Protocol 4 uses `numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct`

Protocol 5 uses `numpy.core.numeric._frombuffer`

Comment: I do not think it's possible without installing the packages and everything. There is no project to transcode between pickle protocols as far as I know. I think protocol 5 though only deals with out of band data, what happens if you literally change the protocol number?

Comment: I don't know much about MLflow, but the fact that you haven't mentioned a `buffers` argument in your `load` call suggests that you don't actually need any protocol 5 features - that, or you're deserializing this wrong. Protocol 5 is all about [out-of-band data buffers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0574/).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica he implies that he can't control the pickling on the producing side

Comment: No, wait, there's a new BYTEARRAY8 opcode that's useful even without out-of-band buffers. I was thinking maybe you could just change the pickle magic number and have it work, but probably not.

Comment: The fact that you're seeing protocol 5 output suggests that you're using cloudpickle rather than standard pickle. Standard pickle uses protocol 4 by default. This is controllable from your end - `mlflow.sklearn.save_model` takes a `serialization_format` argument.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica that's exactly what I thought, I mean, he should changed the second byte from `\x05` to `\x04` and see how it goes

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica he can also analyze the data using pickletools and find if BYTEARRAY8 is used.

Comment: >"mlflow.sklearn.save_model takes a serialization_format argument" Yes. Unfortunately, (a) I cannot control the people who call it. and (b) `serialization_format` is not supported in `mlflow.sklearn.autolog()` that the users surprisingly use. P.S. I've just added `serialization_format` support to `mlflow.sklearn.autolog()`, but it will take a long time for new version to be released and for the users to upgrade. https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/pull/5329

Comment: I've verified that the pickled file uses `BYTEARRAY8`. Updated the question. Maybe it's possible to convert the `BYTEARRAY8` opcode to `BINBYTES8` plus call to the `bytearray` constructor.

Comment: I am having the same issue - wondering if you were able to solve it. thank you! @Ark-kun

Comment: It might be possible to create a pickle "parser/walker" and then use it to detect instantiation of NumPy arrays and re-pickle them to v4 protocol. But it was too much work for the task I had. I worked around the issue, but it's not generic.